# sum trigger on insert Mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table called sum_test with id,a,b,c fields
I need a trigger that calculates the sum of a+b on c but Im new to triggers.
How can I do that on Mysql?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `example` AFTER INSERT ON `sum_test`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE sum_test
SET c= (a+b)
WHERE id = id
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are wanting to set column `c` on the row we are inserting, then we can do like this, in a `BEFORE` insert trigger:

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE TRIGGER `sum_test_bi` BEFORE INSERT ON `sum_test`
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    SET NEW.c = NEW.a + NEW.b ;
 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

---

I don't understand the reference to table `suma`. What does that table have to do with anything?  We note that the condition `id = id` is going to evaluate to TRUE for every row in the table where `id IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: and how can I redo this trigger if user updates column a or b?

Comment: You'd need to define second trigger `sum_test_bu BEFORE UPDATE`... the rest of the trigger definition is identical.